# fetch column from sql data base into html pull down menu using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I am quite new to java script and i am struggling with the following.
I am using php 7 and trying to call data from sql database, the data is a table, but i want to select one column from that table and put it into a pull down menu in html.

So, I used mysqli prepare function as follows. I have two question, the first: can this run inside the same php where another sql query was open.  the second is how to use what is returned (the column in that case) and put it into a pull down menu the user can choose from in html.

what I tried is to put that code inside the code as I saw in another post. but the data cannot be populated.

EDIT:
The database is oracle so i cannot use mysqli, i used instead the following code
but i am getting only the first number in the column and not displaying it in the pull down menu, how can i use foreach to loop over all retrieved numbersand use that in the pull down menu?. I am confused, where to include the select statement for html pull down menu

```
   <td>


<?php
require_once("..//ora_db");
// Create connection
$oracle_db = new ora_database("abc");
// Check connection
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cvbh";
$cursor = $oracle_db->execute_sql($sql);
$counter=0;

 while (OCIFetchInto ($cursor,$row))
  {

    $number= $row[1];

  # echo "<select><option value="number">$number</option></select>";

    $counter ++;
 }
 print_r($number);
?>

<select><option value="number">number</option></select>
    </td>
```

Comment: you realize that you're using a mysql reserved word. Is that your actual query here?

Comment: your html markup is off and there's no javascript here.

Comment: you're also mixing different mysql apis.

Comment: you mean $sqli?

Comment: php tags `<?php ... ?>` are missing in your code !

Comment: yes ofcourse php tags are there, i just forgot to copy them in my code here

Answer (score -1):

First of all there is no need for javascript here.

Answer to your first question: Yes you can run multiple query's on the same page.

Answer to your second question: You can easily generate html code based on your for loop by doing something like this

```
        <select>
        foreach ($stmt->get_result() as $row)
        {
        echo "<option> $row['Column'] </option>";
        }
        </select>
```

Comment: First thanks for ur answer, second based on my code above i am not able to get the column, it does not show up when i echo. Third, i need to put the code in a java script as it will be part of another table so, i cannot just echo

Comment: If you want to output the results in a table I don't see the need for javascript. And if you don't get any result from the query is your database connection working?

Comment: No, Isn't  $mysqli = new mysqli("db") sufficient or does it have to take more than one variable?

Comment: You can read about mysqli constructor here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php but it takes a username and password aswell. Even if you did not create a user the default user is root and empty password.

Comment: Is there a way to use something other than mysqli, because i am giving the right parameters as database name and user name and password and still does not connect

Comment: Try following this link with a test page just to see if it is working or not. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp there is also an example with a PDO database connection.

Comment: i edited the question, can you please with that last step